# std::lower_bound() implementation

Tags: c++, stl

I am curious why std::lower_bound() asks for passing by value for the compare function rather than by reference?

Passing by value means a copy is needed, slowing things down; especially, if someone passes in a "big" compare function object.

Comment: It's often a good candidate for a move. Lambdas, temporary functor objects, function *pointers*.

Comment: Right, probably calling move constructor in the copy constructor?  But I think move exists in C11 recently but this STL algo exists for a long time.  Temporary function object can probably be identified and then optimized by the compiler, but seems like a constructor call per invocation will still happen.  Passing a function pointer is still not as optimal as passing a function object by reference because it can't be possibly inlined.  That's why I raised this question :(

Comment: The move constructor is separate from the copy constructor. I'm not sure about functors, though they could have figured they would probably have zero data members in C++03 or something. I really don't see passing a function pointer as a problem.

Comment: A function pointer requires deference and so the compiler can't do static binding (of course, you can argue that a good compiler might be able to do so but I doubt it is required by the standard).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many if not most comparison objects are stateless and take almost no size (they can't have zero size though). Passing a reference could actually be more expensive than passing a stateless predicate by value (especially if the compiler is able to totally elide the copy).

Comment: This is actually an interesting answer.  I will try to benchmark a bit.  Thanks!